# Chrome Extension Highlighted Text selection chrome.tabs

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm having trouble with chrome extensions,. I have the permission "tabs" but I don't know how to retrieve the selected text on the page WITHOUT< a background page. <---- I change my mind about this, background pages I can have.

This was the scripting:

> var code = document.getSelection().toString();
>   document.getElementsById("q").value = code;

I had placed a `chrome.executeCommand` method (can't remember how the method was oriented), but that didn't work either.
I don't want a background page to prevent lag when this extension is installed. It may not vause much lag when I have a background, but every piece counts. Also, basically my extension will be about a Portable Google It! extension and if you highlight/select text that it will set the value of the input field automatically. Click 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c7q2puadva2vojf/GsuwWcXHjr to see the my progress so far!

Comment: Why do you need the `tabs` permission ? Why don't you want to have a background-page ? How is your extension supposed to work (e.g. when should it get the selected text) ? In what context do you want to use the selected text ? What does your manifest look like ? Please, give more info !

Comment: So you want to select some text in a tab, then click on the browser-action button on the top right, the popup shows up and the input field is populated with the selected text. Is that right ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem yes, technically

Answer (score 6):

(Among several possible approaches) you can achieve what you want like this:

1. When your popup is loaded, use **[`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)** to inject some code into the tab's web-page.
2. From the injected code find and return the selected text.
3. Populate the "search-query" input field with the returned text.
4. when the "search" button is clicked, open a new tab with the google search results.

---

Below is the source code of a sample extension that does exactly that:

**In *maifest.json*:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
}
```

**In *popup.html*:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google It!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="inp" size="20" placeholder="Search query..." />
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Google It!" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**In *popup.js*:**

```
/* The URL for the Google search */
var google = 'http://google.com/#q=';

/* The function that finds and returns the selected text */
var funcToInject = function() {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = range.cloneContents().textContent;
    return selectedText;
};
/* This line converts the above function to string
 * (and makes sure it will be called instantly) */
var jsCodeStr = ';(' + funcToInject + ')();';

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    /* Find our input elements from `popup.html` */
    var inp = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]#inp');
    var btn = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]#btn');

    /* Open a new tab with the search results */
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var query = encodeURIComponent(inp.value);
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: google + query });
    });

    /* Inject the code into all frames of the active tab */
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: jsCodeStr,
        allFrames: true
    }, function(selectedTextPerFrame) {

        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            /* Report any error */
            alert('ERROR:\n' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        } else if ((selectedTextPerFrame.length > 0)
                && (typeof(selectedTextPerFrame[0]) === 'string')) {
            /* The results are as expected, 
             * populate the "search-query" input field */
            inp.value = selectedTextPerFrame[0].trim();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just to inject a simple variable script then return it to the extension:
var text = window.getSelection().toString();
return text;

Comment: @Agentleader1: I don't really see how it is easier (it's the exact same method, just a couple of lines shorter). The reason I chose to use an **[Immediately-invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)** is to prevent conflicts. It is always a good practice to use IIFE when injecting code right into the web-pages JS context.

Comment: @Agentleader1: BTW, did you try my proposed solution ? If it worked for you, please consider accepting/upvoting the answer.

Comment: I am not sure but my js does not work. I really don't remember why or how. Did you try it for yourself to see if it works. Also I have already provided my extension in progress.

Comment: @Agentleader1: Yes, I did try it myself and it worked (what would be the purpose of providing sample code that does not work). I would suggest trying it yourself (just the code I provide) and if it works you can incorporate to your existing code. Then you will know that if it stops working, it is an issue with the rest of your code (and you can still accept/upvote my answer :)).

Comment: @gkalpak I tried this code and it works perfectly.but when I try to populate a `div` or `p`, it doesn't work.This only works for `input`s.Do you have any solution to this?

Comment: @gkalpak It works now.I had used `.value` for populating a `p`.It started working as soon as I changed it to `.innerHTML`.