# Chrome Extension, how to get highlighted text

Tags: google-chrome

I'm looking for a way to highlight a text on a website and when I press the extension button the extension will receive that text (so I can do stuff with it).

Do I just use window.getSelection?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you done already? you have try use `window.getSelection` ? what's the problem?

Comment: This is what I have so far:

`    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
         var selection;  
         selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension Highlighted Text selection chrome.tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534685/chrome-extension-highlighted-text-selection-chrome-tabs)